# Correct Razor syntax in helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This should be fairly trivial, yet, it's not. I'm trying to use a Razor helper to output a bunch of links, but the syntax appears to become inherently ugly. Can someone with good Razor knowledge help me clarify how to remove `<text>` tags and potentially balance the tags so I can get rid of the Raw() output?

```
@helper LinkBuilder(string linkText, string action, string controller, List<string> controllersGroup = null) {
bool userHasAccess = securityEngine.HasAccess(userRoles, controller.ToLower(), Permission.View);

<text></text>   @* Razor demands some output first *@

if (userHasAccess == false) {
    <text><li class="disabled" style="@(listItemWidth)"></text>
}
else {
    <text><li style="@(listItemWidth)"></text>
}

if (userHasAccess) {
    @Html.ActionLink(linkText, action, controller)
}
else {
    <span title="@i18n.NoAccess">@linkText</span>
}

@Html.Raw("</li>") @* Without Html.Raw, Razor complains about unmatching tags *@
```

}

The idea is to build a menu using code like this:

```
    <ul>
        @LinkBuilder(i18n.Documents, "Documents", "Product")
        @LinkBuilder(i18n.Reports, "Index", "Report")
        @LinkBuilder(i18n.Committees, "Index", "Committee", new List<string> { "Company", "Person" })
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this and avoid the use of `<text>` elements using conditional attributes

```
bool userHasAccess = ...
<li class=@(userHasAccess ? null : "disabled") style="@(listItemWidth)">
    @if (userHasAccess)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink(linkText, action, controller)
    }
    else
    {
        <span title="@i18n.NoAccess">@linkText</span>
    }
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach worked. But why on earth is Razor so restrictive regarding conditional statements' syntax in (the beginning of) a helper function? I.e. if I add *if (!userHasAccess) listItemClass = "disabled";* everything works, but if I add brackets and an else statement, it crashes.